How to Avoid CORS Issues with m3u8 Video Streaming Using HLS Proxy
I have an m3u8 video link that I want to play using HLS.js in my web application. However, I'm encountering CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issues when trying to load both the m3u8 file and its .ts segment files.
The browser console shows CORS errors for both the m3u8 playlist and the .ts segment files.
How can I set up an HLS proxy to properly handle CORS issues and stream both the m3u8 playlist and the .ts segments?
Any guidance, example code...

"This question needs debugging details" means  that you need to provide testable details like: What browser? What m3u8 video link? What web application (with a demo page showing the problem)? PS: Make sure the links for m3u8 and your web application both start as https:// or else it won't work.
